# How to convert a multicast address string to in_addr or in_addr6

Tags: c, sockets, ipv6, ipv4, datagram

I'm writing a program where a datagram socket should be able to receive multicast datagrams. I already found out that before a host can receive IP multicast datagrams, the host must become a member of one,
or more IP multicast groups with a `setsockopt()` call. The application should work for both IPv4 and IPv6.

The thing that i don't know is how to properly convert my IPv4/IPv6 multicast address string for example `"ff14::60"` into a `in_addr` or `in_addr6` struct for the different `setsockopt()` calls.

I appreciate your help and suggestions!

Comment: The same way you convert any other IP address string.

Comment: @Barmar so `inet_pton()` would work?

Comment: Exactly. It's just an address, the fact that it's multicast is irrelevant when parsing it.

Comment: @Barmar thank you very much! Sometimes the solution can be very simple :-).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `inet_pton()` function can be used for this according to the [manpage](https://linux.die.net/man/3/inet_pton).